# "Si tratta di un problema" versus "È un problema"

Tags: phrase-choice

Okay - Here is the context.
I have found it helpful in my quest to speak Italian to think about things I want to say, and then to attempt translations of them. I have been relying heavily on the dictionary, Google Translator (dangerous, but helpful) and something called Reverso-Contexto, which is very helpful, if confusing. (It shows me actual usages of whatever phrase I am using, pronunciation, and (sometimes very wrong) translations.

I decided that I wanted to say **"My mouth is fighting back. It is a problem."** in re; the difficulty I have in pronouncing some words and phrases in Italian.

My translation, I think, would be as follows;
**La mia bocca sta contrattaccando. È un problema.**
BUT - I keep seeing the following treatment
**Si tratta di un problema.**

***WHY would I add those extra words?  Which version of the sentence most nearly captures the intent of the one I am trying to translate?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that, in this context, the two forms are equivalent. Your version, "È un problema", is more colloquial than the other, but both are commonly used. 
*È un problema* is more direct: generally speaking, when you use it you're not going to provide further explanation on what you're talking about. It's more like a consideration (it is a *problem*, stop). *Si tratta di un problema* leaves the question half open: it is generally followed by some words about the problem you're talking about (but this is not a rule).

---

The verb *trattarsi*, followed by the preposition *di*, comes from *[trattare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trattare/)* and is usually [translated](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/trattare) by the English forms *to deal with*, *to concern*, *to be about*. From the *Treccani* entry (4):

> Molto com. l’espressione impers. **trattarsi di ...** (e spec. **si tratta di ...**) per indicare l’oggetto di un discorso, l’essenza di una questione, la vera natura di un fatto, la cosa che più importa in un determinato momento: *1. vi dirò subito di che cosa si tratta; 2. posso sapere anch’io di che si tratta?; 3. devi pensarci tu, perché è del tuo avvenire che si tratta; 4. non si tratta soltanto di te, ma di tutti noi;*
>    
>   [The impersonal expression *trattarsi di...* (and mainly *si tratta di...*) is a very common one and is used to illustrate the subject of a speech, the essence of a matter, the real nature of an issue, what matters most in a certain moment: *1. I'll tell you what it is about; 2. May I know what it is about?; 3. You have to take care of it since it concerns your future; 4. It's not only about you, but it concerns all of us.*]

[Here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/si-tratta-trattarsi.10520/?hl=it) you may find more examples.

Comment: Thank you.  The added examples link was great, as well.  Sometimes, I find it helps if I read a LOT of different examples...  It slowly sorts itself out in my brain, apparently.

Comment: @Msfolly glad to be of some help!